# When visual studio 2022 .editorconfig is set to filescoped, internalclass Class1 is adjacent, especially in class projects

Tags: editorconfig

When visual studio 2022 .editorconfig is set to filescoped, internalclass Class1 appears adjacent, especially in class projects. Is there a way to fix this?

internalclass Class1
{
}

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue that has been fixed in Visual Studio 2022 17.2 Preview 1: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-class-or-interface-wizard-formatted-/1650105